# Jenkins and git with custom port

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to link a **gitlab** instance with a Jenkins instance. Due to being run in a DC/OS environment I cannot use the standard SSH port 22, so I am running **gitlab** on SSH port 16122 instead.

**Gitlab** displays SSH clone URLs in the format `[git@git.company.de:16122]:user/test.git`, which a normal `git clone` command understands. Also, Jenkins accepts this URI as SCM URI in the configuration screen (as evidenced by the error messages "invalid credentials" vanishing once I set the SSH key as credential that is configured as deploy-key in **Gitlab**.

The problem arises during actually building the job: jenkins for some unknown reason decides to double-urlencode the `[` at the front of the URI and thus the build breaks:

```
Cloning repository %255bgit@git.company.de:16122]:user/test.git
 > git init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from %25255bgit@git.company.de:16122]:user/test.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress %25255bgit@git.company.de:16122]:user/test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress %25255bgit@git.company.de:16122]:user/test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
```

When I look at the raw XML of the job using xxd on the shell, there are no "invisible" ASCII chars or similar in front of the repo URL.

What causes this, and is there a way to fix this without having to manually rewrite every URL to `ssh://git@git.company.de:16122/user/test.git`?

Comment: I ended up using the `ssh://git@git.company.de:16122/user/test.git` way of formatting the URL. 
Did you ever work this out?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. Rewriting sucks but it's the only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the .ssh/config file to use the non standard port on your jenkins machine.

Something like:

```
Host git.company.de
    Hostname=git.company.de
    User=git
    Port=16122
```